# What is the value of a summer project on cv of someone who wants to pursue graduate studies?

Tags: graduate-admissions, research-process, united-states, cv, summer-school

I got accepted in a summer research project in the US with a very famous professor in the field, however, it is so expensive for me.

I am not a US citizen but planning to pursue graduate studies there. I don't have publications yet and by the end of the project, the participants will have to write a paper. How valuable is that for graduate admission?

Comment: Do not work for free. That is exploitative and wrong on behalf of the employer.

Comment: @astronat, that depends on whether any benefit accrues to the professor. If it is just guided student research, there is no issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The experience of working under a well-known professor will impact positively on your profile, and is generally quite valuable for graduate applications. However, you need to take a call on whether the effort you put in is worth the result, and whether this is the only avenue for you to improve your profile.

You say that you're not a US citizen and this is a summer research project in the US, under a famous professor. You also mention that it's going to be very expensive for you. From this, and the general tone of your post, I assume that you're not in the US currently and that you're looking to travel there if possible. You have to settle in, find a place to live, find a sustainable plan for yourself in terms of finances and amenities, and also conduct *publishable* research, all in *one summer.* You need to decide whether all of this is possible.

This is quite a lot of work for one summer. There are going to be easier avenues for you to publish papers, avenues that are worth considering over this.